# How to manually set a diverging color range

Tags: altair, vega-lite, vega

I am using Altair for Python and my current code uses a redyellowblue color scheme which uses the middle color (yellow) accordingly to my domainMid parameter.

```
color=alt.Color('Spline_WW_Diff_Trend:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='redyellowblue',reverse=True, domain=[-3.57,2.270], domainMid=0, clamp=True), legend=alt.Legend(title="Trend"))
```

Which gives me:
[image]

I need to replace the yellow color with the white color. I've switched scheme to range and tried different combinations of Scale parameters, but it doesn't respect my domainMid.

Example:

```
color=alt.Color('Spline_WW_Diff_Trend:Q', scale=alt.Scale(range=['#D4322C', 'white', '#4A74B4'],reverse=True, domain=[-3.57,2.270], domainMid=0, clamp=True), legend=alt.Legend(title="Trend"))
```

This gives me:
[image]

You can notice that the first column (which is all value 0) is showing reddish and not white (as it was supposed to be).

How can I have the same result as in the color scheme (picture one), but, with white instead of yellow?

**Edit:**

The same goes for.

```
range=['blue', 'lightblue', 'white', 'pink', 'red']
```

The mid color is light-blue, not white.

[image]

**Edit 05/12/2022:**

Just to clarify, I would like to achieve this same color scheme: [image]
[image].

This heatmap was created in R, by using the [RdYlBu color pallete](https://rdrr.io/cran/RColorBrewer/man/ColorBrewer.html) (the one with 11 colors) and overwrite the middle (6th color) with white. Then, they increased the number of colors in the pallete to 99, to make the fade look more fluid. Does anyone has any idea on how to achieve that in Altair?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would be to set `range='diverging'`, or to use one of the built-in [diverging color schemes](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/#diverging). For example:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(-10, 20)})

alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    color=alt.Color('x:Q',
      scale=alt.Scale(domainMid=0, scheme='redblue'))
)
```

[image]

If it's important to you that the center value is exactly white, you could use a condition to override the colormap for this value. For example:

```python
alt.Chart(df).mark_rect().encode(
    x='x:O',
    color=alt.condition(
      'datum.x == 0',
      alt.value('white'),
      alt.Color('x:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domainMid=0, scheme='redblue')))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @jakevdp. Setting diverging didn't help, but the redblue color scheme did help. I'm checking with the client if this is satisfactory. In the meantime, what would be the complete (and harder) approach to have the mid color as white (It could be in the using the redblue/redyellowblue schemas or manually setting the colors)?

Comment: You can set a custom color range with `domainMid` set to the middle mark; for example: `alt.Scale(range=['blue', 'lightblue', 'white', 'pink', 'red'], domainMid=0)`

Comment: Thank you again @jakevdp. It is showing the mid color as light-blue, not white. I've edited the main post with the result.

Comment: OK, see edited answer.

Comment: @jakedvp It replaced only the color on 0, but I'm looking to change the surrounding color ramp to colors based on white. Please, check on the main post what I'm trying to achieve. Sorry to bother you again, but this change is back on my priority list.